# How to trap ERR when using 'set -e' in Bash

Tags: bash, interrupt-handling

I have a simple script :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
trap "echo BOO!" ERR 

function func(){
    ls /root/
}

func
```

I would like to trap ERR if my script fails (as it will here b/c I do not have the permissions to look into /root). However, when using `set -e` it is not trapped. Without `set -e` ERR is trapped.

According to the bash man page, for `set -e` :

> ... A trap on ERR, if set, is executed before the  shell  exits. ...

Why isn't my trap executed?  From the man page it seems like it should.

Comment: As an aside: it's better to _single-quote_ your trap handlers, unless you explicitly want variable references in it expanded _up front_.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

**[chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35800457/45375) is the best solution**: If you want **to combine `set -e` (same as: `set -o errexit`) with an `ERR` trap, also use `set -o errtrace` (same as: `set -E`)**.

**In short: use `set -eE`** in lieu of just `set -e`:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eE  # same as: `set -o errexit -o errtrace`
trap 'echo BOO!' ERR 

function func(){
  ls /root/
}

# Thanks to -E / -o errtrace, this still triggers the trap, 
# even though the failure occurs *inside the function*.
func
```

<sup>A more sophisticated example `trap` example that prints the message in red and also prints the exit code:

`trap 'printf "\e[31m%s: %s\e[m\n" "BOO!" $?' ERR`</sup>

---

`man bash` says about `set -o errtrace` / `set -E`:

> If set, any trap on ERR is inherited by shell functions, command substitutions, and commands executed in a subshell environment. The ERR trap is normally not inherited in such cases.

What I believe is happening:

- *Without* `-e`: The `ls` command fails inside your function, and, due to being the last command in the function, the function reports `ls`'s nonzero exit code to the caller, your top-level script scope. In *that scope*, the `ERR` trap is in effect, and it is invoked (but note that execution will continue, unless you explicitly call `exit` from the trap).
- *With* `-e` (but without `-E`): The `ls` command fails *inside your function*, and because `set -e` is in effect, Bash *instantly* exits, *directly from the function scope* - and since there is no `ERR` trap in effect *there* (because it wasn't inherited from the parent scope), your trap is not called.

While the `man` page is not incorrect, I agree that this behavior is not exactly obvious - you have to infer it.

Comment: Thanks, I will. Also instead of `ls /root/` when I run `bash try.sh` which has `#!/bin/bash
exit 1`, it does not catched by the `trap`, is there any way to catch the called script if it is exited ?

Comment: @alper There's a separate `EXIT` trap invoked when the script exits, for whatever reason, and whether successfully or not. To only act on _non-zero_ exit codes, you must check `$?`; e.g.: `trap 'ec=$?; (( ec != 0 )) && echo "Exited with failure: $ec"' EXIT`

Answer (score 17):

You need to use `set -o errtrace` for the function to inherit the trap.

Comment: Not necessarily, if you use `shopt -s extdebug`.

Answer (score 14):

We have these options for debugging:

- `-e` Exit immediately on failure
- `-E` If set, any trap on ERR is inherited by shell functions
- `-u` Exit when there is an unbound variable
- `-o` Give a option-name to set

  - pipefail The return values of last (rightmost) command (exit code)
- `-v` Print all shell input lines as they are read
- `-x` Print trace of commands

---

For handling the errors we can catch directory with **trap**

```
trap 'echo >&2 "Error - exited with status $? at line $LINENO' ERR
```

Or a better version [ref](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39623/trap-err-and-echoing-the-error-line) :

```
trap 'echo >&2 "Error - exited with status $? at line $LINENO:";
         pr -tn $0 | tail -n+$((LINENO - 3)) | head -n7' ERR
```

Or a function:

```
function __error_handing__(){
    local last_status_code=$1;
    local error_line_number=$2;
    echo 1>&2 "Error - exited with status $last_status_code at line $error_line_number";
    perl -slne 'if($.+5 >= $ln && $.-4 <= $ln){ $_="$. $_"; s/$ln/">" x length($ln)/eg; s/^\D+.*?$/\e[1;31m$&\e[0m/g;  print}' -- -ln=$error_line_number $0
}
```

and call it this way:

```
trap  '__error_handing__ $? $LINENO' ERR
```

Answer (score 5):

Replace `ERR` with `EXIT` and it will work.

The syntax of the `trap` command is: `trap [COMMANDS] [SIGNALS]`

For more info, please read http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html

Comment: While this is a viable workaround (albeit not needed, if `set -o errtrace` is used), you should mention that `EXIT` is also called in the event of _successful_ termination, so you'd need to add a conditional such as `if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] …` to the handler.