# How to get error code and command output when using set -e?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to catch the error code of a command and assign the output of a command to a variable in an if statement. My code looks like this:

```
if ! ret=$(<some_command>); then
    rc=$?
    echo "<some_command> returned with exit code: $rc"
    echo "$ret"
fi
```

Here I want to assign the output of a command to `ret` and assign only the error code of `<some_command>` to `rc`. Since this script have `set -e`, I cannot just run the command standalone. As soon as the command fails, the script exits, but I do not want to exit the script, rather get the error code as well as the error into an variable. How to get this working?

Comment: Don't use `set -e` since you don't want the behavior it provides. In general `set -e` is best avoided as you usually want to do **something** when a failure occurs in a script, even if it's just print an error message, and `set -e`s behavior is convoluted and changes between bash versions. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 for more info.

Comment: If you don't want to exit the script on failure, then yeah, don't use `-e`. If you want to retrieve the status code in order to log it before exit, you could use traps, like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800082/how-to-trap-err-when-using-set-e-in-bash)

Answer (score 3):

`set -e` is a nonissue here: its behavior is disabled inside `if` and in any other "checked" context; the `!` is what's causing your exit status to be suppressed.

Take away the `!`, and move the error handling into an `else` clause:

```
if ret=$(some_command); then :; else
    rc=$?
    echo "<some_command> returned with exit code: $rc"
    echo "$ret"
fi
```

...or, perhaps more idiomatically (as `||` branching on a command's exit status *also* marks it as checked and suppresses `set -e`):

```
ret=$(some_command) || {
  rc=$?
  echo "<some_command> returned with exit code: $rc"
  echo "$ret"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `!` command just negates the current exit code. For instance, after `!false`, the value of `$?` would be 0. In your case, `rc` will always be 0.

To retrieve the exit code for later processing, you have to collect it after the command has been executed.  If you really insist in using `set -e`, which IMO is a bad idea, you can do it like this:

```
rc=0
ret=$(some_command) || rc=$?
if ((rc > 0))
then
  echo "<some_command> returned with exit code: $rc"
  echo "$ret"
fi
```

Comment: "no-op" is a little inaccurate, because it negates the true/false status of the rc, as you said. Solution is on point, though. :)

Comment: @PaulHodges : Fixed it. Thanks a lot. I dislike inaccuracies in language.

Comment: Me too. I am *Pedantic Man!* My cape it at the cleaners, though... ;)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Well, depends on the definition of _a lot_. In any case, I find your solution more beautiful than mine. May I suggest that you post it as answer?

Comment: Charles and Ed are my heroes. :)

Comment: @PaulHodges, ...we no longer work together, but I was impressed enough with Ed's awk knowledge (and war stories from interacting with the Bell Labs crew) that I hired him once. :)

Comment: I was tempted to drive up - I'm in St. Louis - and buy your guys lunch more than once!

Comment: @PaulHodges never let Charles and I no longer working together stop you from buying us food :-).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the consensus here - generally just don't use `set -e`.
Consider maybe a [trap](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-trap-command) instead, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50296873/8656552).

Second, *most* bash checks against a condition will "consume" the "exception". I'm sure there's better terminology, but test it for yourself; if you check for a fail immediately, things like `set -e` or a `trap` won't usually see the fail, and you can handle it explicitly.

user1934428's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76721404/8656552) does this with a double-pipe to explicitly check the exit status and set the value on a fail.

Be careful - even testing only for *success* is likely to have this effect. See below.

```
$: cat tst
#! bash
set -e
cmd=( bogus command )
# check fail only (#1), success only (#2), both (#3)
"${cmd[@]}" || echo "yep, failed #1"
"${cmd[@]}" && echo "worked fine! #2" # doesn't print
"${cmd[@]}" && echo "worked fine!" || echo "oops! #3"
if "${cmd[@]}"  # the if is a test, "catches" the fail
then echo "won't get here"
else rc=$?
     echo "<${cmd[@]}> returned with exit code: $rc - #4"
fi
# running it without checking here, #5
"${cmd[@]}" # uncaught, set -e kills the script here
echo "This doesn't print! #5"
```

The `cmd` array is just an easy way to make sure the `echo` doesn't have to be separately maintained.

Running it looks like this:

```
$: ./tst
./tst: line 5: bogus: command not found
yep, failed #1
./tst: line 6: bogus: command not found
./tst: line 7: bogus: command not found
oops! #3
./tst: line 8: bogus: command not found
<bogus command> returned with exit code: 127 - #4
./tst: line 14: bogus: command not found
```

Hope that helps.

## addendum

We totally did NOT address the output capture, but you seem to have that; and I completely agree that it's probably better to avoid the "not" (`!`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

if ! ret=$(some_command); then
    rc=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
    printf '<some_command> returned with exit code: %d\n' "$rc"
    printf '%s\n' "$ret"
fi
```

- Using the built-in [PIPESTATUS](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PIPESTATUS) array in Bash is a common way to get the return status of a negated command.
- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why I replaced `echo` with `printf`.  `echo "$var"` doesn't work in general.